# Photos MacOS: After restoring whole library "Show in moments" are disabled on photos in Shared albums

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra, photos

I messed up my Photos library (the mumble.photoslibrary folder) and restored it from my Time Machine backup.   Photos rebuilt the database when opened the first time, and everything seem to work properly again.

Unfortunately my shared albums appears to have lost the connection to the originals so I cannot right click on a shared photo and go to the original photo ("Show in moments") in my library any more as the option is greyed out.  I can, however, "Import" it.

This is under High Sierra 10.13.6, and I'm *not* using iCloud Storage (except Photo Stream due to the automatic import from my iPhone).

Is this a well-known problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you edit the post to say if you disable iCloud Photo Library or enable it? That adds a layer of complication and perhaps a totally easy fix. ( which would be to download from the cloud and not time machine. https://daringfireball.net/2018/10/icloud_photo_library_start_over ) my guess is you didn’t mention iCloud since you opted out of that.

Comment: @bmike I'm not using iCloud for this.  My library is so large that I would need a more expensive plan than I would like (plus in these Snowden-times I'd like to control what is put out there).